# Expand/Collapse grid column on WPF expander click event

Tags: wpf, mvvm, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, expander

I have a MVVM application. In main window I have put below grid with 2 columns. In column 2 I have placed an WPF expander and I set it as collapsed by default (IsExpanded="False"). When application executes I would like grid column 1 to fill the entire width of the grid and grid column 2 with width 0 (collapsed). So when I click in the expander I want grid column 2 to expand to take 0.47* of width. Then if I click the expander again, I would like grid column 1 to fill the entire width of the grid and grid column 2 to be collapsed (width=0). How can I do this?  Below code is not working.

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>            
    <RowDefinition Height="47.5*" />           
    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />            
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.47*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<controls:UCIndicationsOfUse Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                             Width="auto"
                             Height="auto"
                             DataContext="{Binding}" />

<controls:UCPData    Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                     Width="auto"
                     Height="auto"
                     DataContext="{Binding}" />

<Expander Grid.Row="0" 
          Grid.RowSpan="2"
          Grid.Column="1"  
          Width="25"            
          ExpandDirection="Left"
          IsExpanded="False"
          HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <Expander.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="Settings">
            <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
            </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
        </TextBlock>
    </Expander.Header>
</Expander>
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have added Collapsed and Expanded events to the expander:

```
<Expander Grid.Row="0" 
          Grid.RowSpan="2"
          Grid.Column="1"  
          Width="25"
          Collapsed="Expander_Collapsed"
          Expanded="Expander_Expanded"            
          ExpandDirection="Left"
          IsExpanded="False"
          HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <Expander.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="Settings">
            <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
            </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
        </TextBlock>
    </Expander.Header>
</Expander>
```

And then from view code-behind:

```
private void Expander_Collapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ColumnDefinition c = this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions[1];
    c.Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
    this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions.RemoveAt(1);
    this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions.Insert(1, c);
}

private void Expander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ColumnDefinition c = this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions[1];
    c.Width = new GridLength(0.47, GridUnitType.Star);
    this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions.RemoveAt(1);
    this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions.Insert(1, c);
}
```

I think this not break MVVM pattern since it is a task for the view.

Comment: If you are using a mvvm pattern ,why not put code-behind into your viewModel? I think it's better.

Comment: @FranklinLee ok, using commands? Yes I thought it but I think this is a task that related to the view.